# How to mock bindActionCreators using jest enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, enzyme

in js file

```
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  const MyActions = bindActionCreators(MyActions, dispatch);

  return {
    actions: {
      method1: () => {
        MyActions.myActionMethod();
      },
}
```

Now I want to test if calling of method1 dispatches MyActions.myActionMethod

my .test.js code

```
 it("Should call myAction", () => {
    jest
      .spyOn(MyActions, "myActionMethod")
      .mockImplementation(() => {
        console.log("calling mock imple");

      });

    enzymeWrapper.props().actions.method1();
  });
```

can anyone suggest to me how to mock bindActionCreators ?

Comment: got any solution on this bro?

Comment: Nope, I haven't found yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for it, we need to spy or mock actions before `enzymeWrapper` creation which means before calling `shallow` method.